# Git - create branch from another branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

I am working on a project with some other developers. I created a branch `xx` from the master branch, made some changes and submitted a pull request.

The pull request has not been merged yet but I need to continue working on some other issues/changes. That requires me to work on a separate branch from `xx`.

For this new branch, should I be creating it from `xx` or from the `master`? If I create it from `master`, the changes from `xx` won't be in there and those changes fix some fundamental bugs in the code. And if I create a branch from `xx`, when I create a PR for this new branch, it will have the commits from `xx` as well - which will lead to a conflict.

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to create the second branch (I'll call it `xx2`) from `xx` and work on top of it, as long as it semantically makes sense. A completely new feature should be branched off `master`, of course.

When `xx` is merged and you later issue a pull request for `xx2`, the commits from `xx` have already been merged and will not be merged again. At least if you did not perform any rebase or other history-rewriting options. Even if you did, this will not lead to conflicts, since the changes introduced will be the same.

Comment: The important part is that a hard dependency is made on the modifications done on the xx branch when xx2 is made, meaning that if someone later decides that none of the modifications done on the xx branch should be merged into master or whatever, but xx2 should, then it is important to realize that any changes present in xx when xx2 was made will be included with xx2, since they're also part of the xx2 branch.

Comment: That is of course true, but I see no problem here. When the modifications from `xx` are rejected, they will probably be rejected again when proposed in `xx2`. And since the `xx2` changes are nonfunctional without the `xx` changes, theres no use to merge them when the changes from `xx` were not.

Answer (score 1):

Since your workings is related with `xx` branch, so you can continue develop on `xx` branch.

If the PR you submitted is not approved after you finish the second working on `xx` branch. The new commits will automatically added in the PR.

If the PR you submitted is approved before you finish the second working on `xx` branch, you can submit a new PR.